# Android lifecycle 2.4.0 leads to unresolved references

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I was using lifecycle version 2.3.1 but wanted to upgrade to 2.4.0
While doing so, I realized that now the imports for `kotlinx.coroutines.launch`, `kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers` and `kotlinx.coroutines.withContext` lead to unresolved references.

Below are my current dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // ViewModel utilities for Compose
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Annotation processor
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"
}
```

And an example of a ViewModel that's not working:

```kotlin
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Patterns
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.psy.myapplication.R
import com.psy.myapplication.auth.model.User
import com.psy.myapplication.auth.register.data.remote.RemoteRegisterDataSource
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.IO
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import com.psy.myapplication.core.Result

val TAG: String = "REGISTER"

class RegisterViewModel(private val dataSource: RemoteRegisterDataSource) : ViewModel() {
    private val mutableRegisterFormState = MutableLiveData<RegisterFormState>()
    val registerFormState: LiveData<RegisterFormState> = mutableRegisterFormState;

    private val mutableRegisterResult = MutableLiveData<RegisterResult>()
    val registerResult: LiveData<RegisterResult> = mutableRegisterResult

    fun register(email: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.v(TAG, "Launched register")
            val result = withContext(IO) {
                dataSource.register(User(email, password))
            }

            if (result is Result.Success){
                mutableRegisterResult.value = RegisterResult(success = result.data)
            }
            else if (result is Result.Error) {
                mutableRegisterResult.value = RegisterResult(error = result.exception.message)
            }
            else {
                mutableRegisterResult.value = RegisterResult(defaultError = R.string.register_error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the kotlin code, I get errors while trying to call viewModelScope.launch and withContext(IO), getting unresolved references for launch, withContext and Dispatchers.IO

EDIT: Ok, so apparently the errors are not actual errors because the app still compiles and runs fine, it just shows me that there are errors. Invalidating caches, restarting, clean & rebuild, all of these didn't work.